# USB NIC not initialized on boot

Tags: linux, usb, hardware-detection

I have a server running on a Rpi4 that runs multiple services via LXD, one of which is a VPN Service. Due to restrictions on my ISP, I route port forwarding through a paid VPN provider to the server (outside of LXD). I wanted the LXD VPN service to be connected directly to the home network and not the bridge network setup by LXD, and in the end I ended up connecting a second USB NIC and attach it directly to the LXD container. This proved to be the most stable solution and it works great.

The only issue that I am having is that the USB NIC is not initialized at boot for some reason. I must unplug/re-plug the device after boot to have it show up and not sure why. It's not that big of a deal since this machine is hardly ever turned off, but it bugs me not knowing the reason.

This is from `lshw`

```
*-usb:1
    description: Communication device
    product: USB 10/100 LAN
    vendor: CoreChips
    physical id: 4
    bus info: usb@1:1.4
    version: 20.00
    serial: 00E0D9003D31
    capabilities: usb-2.10 ethernet
    configuration: driver=cdc_ether maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

It's only a base100, but my internet is also only 100/100, and this cost me less than half compared to a 1G NIC that would never be fully utilized anyway.

This device is loaded as a storage device during boot.

```
*-usb:1
    description: Mass storage device
    product: USB 10/100 LAN
    vendor: CoreChips
    physical id: 4
    bus info: usb@1:1.4
    version: 20.00
    serial: 00E0D9003D31
    capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
    configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

Apparently it has a small ROM with Windows drivers on it.

```
$ blkid /dev/sr0 
/dev/sr0: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2019-10-18-17-20-33-00" LABEL="SR9900" TYPE="iso9660"

$ mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/rom/
$ ls /tmp/rom/
AUTORUN.INF  CoreChips.ico  sr9900_sfx.exe
```

After I unplug it and plug it back in, it's loaded correctly as a NIC and `/dev/sr0` is gone.

Why one thing at boot and another after boot? Should it not consistently identify it as one thing or another? Or is this does not kernel module load order? And if this has both a NIC and ROM, should it not initialize both at the same time, like attaching two devices through a hub?

Most importantly, is there something that can be thrown into a boot script or a config file, that will reset this device after boot, like simulating a unplug/re-plug? That would at least allow one to reboot the server without having to manually do this every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of those weird USB devices that *at first* present themselves as a virtual CD-ROM device containing a Setup.exe for Windows drivers, unless the NIC-specific driver is already loaded and uses some magic commands to switch the device into NIC mode.

3G/4G modems do that a lot, even to the point that a whole "usb_modeswitch" project has been created just to catalogue various ways to switch modems (and sometimes printers) into their normal mode. Some devices rely on usb_modeswitch, some on the kernel driver doing the necessary magic. (However, if you don't have usb_modeswitch installed yet, *don't* install it, it may make things worse for certain devices.)

But the usb_modeswitch helper is only triggered via udev rules when the device is *added.* If the device was detected in the initramfs, which has a minimal set of tools and udev rules, then it won't be switched at that time – and nothing asks the "main" udev instance to do it again later. Try the following to re-trigger udev rules for a specific USB device:

```
udevadm trigger -v -y usb -p ID_VENDOR=CoreChips
```

1. First try including the whole NIC driver in your initramfs  (via Debian's initramfs-tools), in case its presence alone causes it to have priority over the general "USB storage" driver. It looks like your NIC should be using the `sr9800` kernel module, though it ends up using `cdc_ether` instead, but try including both.
2. Also check `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/bConfigurationValue` for the simplest approach to mode switching. A USB device can offer several "configurations" to the host; writing the correct number to this file would be enough to switch modes. If it turns out to be just a matter of USB configurations, create an udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/90-nic.rules and figure out how to include it in your initramfs:

   ```
   ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="CoreChips", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="USB 10/100 LAN", ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="123"
   ```
3. Finally check if usb_modeswitch contains a configuration file for your device's USB VID:PID (not shown in your lshw dumps; use `lsusb` to obtain it). If it does, then your initramfs will need to include the usb_modeswitch udev rules, the actual executable, and the configuration files.